# Get text from span using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba

I'm tryin to get some MLB stats from the [URL](https://sports.yahoo.com/mlb/players/9329/), and I can't get the date (**Jun 19**)  from the below  html element. Can you give me a hand with this ?

> <td class="Px(cell-padding-x) Py(cell-padding-y) Va(m) Ta(start) Fw(500) Whs(nw) Pos(r) Cnt(cq):h::a Pos(a):h::a Bgc(table-hover):h::a Start(0):h::a T(-5000px):h::a H(10000px):h::a W(100%):h::a Z(-1):h::a"><span class=""><span>Jun 19</span></span></td>

I have tried diverse methods but nothing works. See below my last try .

```
Sub MBL_player()
    Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
    Dim htmlEle As IHTMLElement
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 2
    
    Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
    ieObj.Visible = True
    ieObj.navigate "https://sports.yahoo.com/mlb/players/9329/"
    
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:05")
    
    Dim tables As Object
    Set tables = ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("table graph-table W(100%) Ta(start) Bdcl(c) Mb(56px) Ov(h)")

        text = span.innerText
    
    ' Check if there are at least two tables on the page
    If tables.Length >= 2 Then
        Dim secondTable As Object
        Set secondTable = tables(1) ' Index 1 represents the second table
        
        For Each htmlEle In secondTable.getElementsByClassName("Bgc(table-hover):h")
            With ActiveSheet
                .Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
                .Range("B" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(1).textContent
                .Range("C" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(2).textContent
                .Range("D" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(3).textContent
                .Range("E" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(4).textContent
                .Range("F" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(5).textContent
                .Range("G" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(6).textContent
                .Range("H" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(7).textContent
                .Range("I" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(8).textContent
                .Range("J" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(9).textContent
                .Range("K" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(10).textContent
                .Range("L" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(11).textContent
                .Range("M" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(12).textContent
                .Range("N" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(13).textContent
                .Range("O" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(14).textContent
            End With
        
            i = i + 1
        Next htmlEle
    Else
        MsgBox "The page does not contain at least two tables."
    End If
    
    ieObj.Quit
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there's no need to get the span element in order to get to the text.  You can simply do the following...

```
.Range("A" & i).Value = htmlEle.Children(0).textContent
```

Note, however, when Internet Explorer displays the web page, the first column of the second table is blank.

Comment: Hi Brian,, What i need is to pull the "date" and as you can see that is not directly in the TD class. In one level below in the span.                                                              td class="Px(cell-padding-x) Py(cell-padding-y) Va(m) Ta(start) Fw(500) Whs(nw) Pos(r) Cnt(cq):h::a Pos(a):h::a Bgc(table-hover):h::a Start(0):h::a T(-5000px):h::a H(10000px):h::a W(100%):h::a Z(-1):h::a">                                                            
 <span class="">                                                                                          
 <span>Jun 19</span>

Comment: As I mentioned in my post, when I run your code and it navigates to your URL using  Internet Explorer, the first column of the second table is blank.  So the line I posted will correctly return a blank.  It looks like you may need to use some other method to access that information.  Try using Selenium instead of Internet Explorer.